# Django form field not rendering when using custom getattr templatetag

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Why is it that when I'm writing

```
{% with "answer_1" as ans %}
    {{ form|getattr:ans }}
{% endwith %}
```

I get

```
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7fdea0f0a210>
```

in my template, but when I'm writing

```
{{ form.answer_1 }}
```

I get the textfield rendered correctly?

My getattribute templatetag looks like this:

```
@register.filter(name='getattr')
def getattribute(value, arg):
    if hasattr(value, arg):
        return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and arg in value:
        return value[arg]
    else:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
```

It is very important for me to be able to render textfields using `{% with %}` tag, as my form contains many answers and I wish to iterate them and display a textfield for each one.

Any help would be welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is probably with your `getattr` filter, and not your use of the `with` statement. Using `{{ form|getattr:"answer_1" }}` would probably give you the same result as the `with` statement.

Comment: Also, is that your real code? For a bound form, I would expect `hasattr(value, arg)` and `hasattr(value, 'has_key')` to return False. So I would expect your filter to return `settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` instead.

Comment: @Alasdair Indeed this is something I've noticed too. My filter was returning `settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` so I've added this line in `__init__` method of my form class: `setattr(self, 'answer_%d' % i, self.fields['answer_%d' % i])`. Is this wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you are using `self.fields['answer_1']`, which is a CharField. You should use the bound field `self['answer_1']`.

Comment: I don't like the template filter + setattr approach very much, so I've suggested a couple of alternatives in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a different template filter

I don't think that the `getattr` template filter is very suitable for your purposes. I don't like the `has_key` check, because it will return False, even though `'field_name' in Form` is `True`.

You might be able to get the template tag to work by setting attributes on the form, but it seems hacky to me. A better approach would be to use a different template filter.

If you have a `form`, then you can access the field `answer_1` with `form['answer_1']`. Using this knowledge, it's easy to create a more suitable template filter.

```
@register.filter(name='get_form_field')
def get_form_field(form, field_name):
    try:
        return form[field_name]
    except KeyError:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
```

Then, in your template, you can do

```
{{ form|get_form_field:"answer_1" }}
```

Or, if you are using the `with` template tag:

```
{% with "answer_1" as ans %}
    {{ form|get_form_field:ans }}
{% endwith %}
```

## Or try a different approach

Actually, I'm not sure that you need a special template filter at all. You could add a method to your form, that returns a list of the fields you want to display.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def answer_fields(self):
        return [self['answer_%d' % x] for range(1, 5)]
```

Then in your template, loop through the list and render them.

```
{% for field in form.answer_fields %}
    {{ form.answer_fields }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This new template filter suits my needs and works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: About the second approach, I'm not sure you have correctly written that method, maybe bad indentation, but I don't see any list returned.

Comment: Happy to hear that the new filter works! I've fixed the method in the second approach now.